# Непонятное изменение значений в массиве при изменении значения NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, строки

При изменении значения NSMutableString после записи в массив, изменяется и значения в массиве, так и должно быть? Или как объяснить его изменение?

Вот код для примера:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
NSMutableString *name = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[name setString:@"Alice"];

names[0] = name;
NSLog(@"%@",names);

[name setString:@"0"];
NSLog(@"%@",names);
```

Вот вывод программы:

```
Alice
0
```

Хотя должно быть:

```
Alice
Alice
```

При замене NSMutableString на NSString выводит как и надо

Comment: С NSMuatableString можно проводить различные операции: изменять, добавлять текст и т.д., а NSString не может изменяться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну попробую.

В первом случае: вы присваиваете своей string значение. Поскольку это поинтер, он указывает на какую то область памяти (допустим 0x1, где содержится текст 'Alice'). После этого вы присваиваете то же значение и в массив (опять же первый элемент массива указывает на 0x1 - 'Alice'). потом вы меняете значение строки, и поскольку строка mutable она мутирует и в 0x1 записывается новое значение '0'. Из за того, что первый элемент массива все еще указывает на 0x1 получается, что там тоже новое значение.

Второй случай (замена на немутируемый NSString): начало такое же - строка указывает на 0x1 'Alice' и массив туда же. когда вы меняете значение строки, она не мутирует, а записывается в новую область памяти (например 0x2 - '0'), то строка содержит то, что в 0x2, а массив все еще указывает на 0x1.